# Magento ORM to get product collection either sale OR in stock

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, magento-community

How to get a combine product collection with condition either discounted products OR in stock?

```
    // get product collection
    // get product collection
    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->joinField('category_id', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id',
            'product_id = entity_id', null, 'left')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => array('finset' => $this->mainCategories['ids'])));

    // Get Sale products
    $collection->addFinalPrice()
        ->getSelect()
        ->where('price_index.final_price < price_index.price');
    // end
    $collection->getSelect()->group('e.entity_id');
```

// in stock

```
// get product collection
    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->joinField('category_id', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id',
            'product_id = entity_id', null, 'left')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => array('finset' => $this->mainCategories['ids'])))
        ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('eq' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED))
    ;

    // Get Ready stock products
    Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')->addInStockFilterToCollection($collection);
    // end
    $collection->getSelect()->group('e.entity_id');
```

i don't know how to combine them, or using the query in magento way (orm way) in one go.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
// get product collection
    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->joinField('category_id', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id',
            'product_id = entity_id', null, 'left')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => array('finset' => $this->mainCategories['ids'])))
        ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('eq' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED))
    ;

    // Get Ready stock products
    Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')->addInStockFilterToCollection($collection);
    // end
    $collection->addFinalPrice()
        ->getSelect()
        ->where('price_index.final_price < price_index.price');
    $collection->getSelect()->group('e.entity_id');
```

**OR solution 2**
  you can get all product ids by

```
   $collection=$collection->getgetAllIds(); 
   $collection1=$collection1->getgetAllIds(); 


$resultcollection = array_merge($collection, $collection1);
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' =>  $resultcollection));
```

Comment: it will become AND instead of OR

Comment: @doniking added another solution test that and feedback

Comment: i have added my own solution. Really appreciate your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this query, it takes 7 seconds in my localhost. it is ok though as this is run through command line or cron.

```
        $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->joinField('category_id', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id',
            'product_id = entity_id', null, 'left')
        ->joinField('inventory_in_stock', 'cataloginventory/stock_item', 'is_in_stock', 'product_id=entity_id')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => array('finset' => $this->mainCategories['ids'])));

    // Get Sale products
    $collection->addFinalPrice()
        ->getSelect()
        ->where('price_index.final_price < price_index.price OR ((at_inventory_in_stock.use_config_manage_stock = 0 AND at_inventory_in_stock.manage_stock=1 AND at_inventory_in_stock.is_in_stock=1) OR (at_inventory_in_stock.use_config_manage_stock = 0 AND at_inventory_in_stock.manage_stock=0) OR (at_inventory_in_stock.use_config_manage_stock = 1 AND at_inventory_in_stock.is_in_stock=1)) ');
```